# interprete error: No such file or directory [Bash]

Tags: bash

I'm starting with bash scripting, but I can't execute any code due to this error, here is an example of a basic code:

```
#! /bin/bash/ 

for x in $# 
  do 
  echo $x  
  wc - l $x 
  Done
```

I'm on a virtual machine on Linux Fedora.

Comment: There's a space too much between the dash and the l character in your wc command.

Comment: I alredy tried to remove them, it doesn't work at all

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Remove `/` after `bash` and replace `Done` with `done`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary with minor improvements/changes to the formatting:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in $#; do 
  echo "$x"
  wc -l "$x"
done
```

I guess `$#` is still to be replaced by `"${@}"`.